# pass json data collectio into DataTable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I trying to insert json collection in datatable using jQuery.
This is my code:

```
      function reloadseekers(vacancy){
                    if (vacancy) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '/getseekers/' + vacancy,
                            method: "GET",
                            dataType: "json",
                            cache: false,
                            success: function (data) {
                                $.each(data.appseekers, function (index) {
                                    $('#evaluated_list_table').dataTable({
                                        "paging": true,
                                        "lengthChange": true,
                                        "searching": true,
                                        "ordering": true,
                                        "info": true,
                                        "autoWidth": true,
                                        "data": data.appseekers,
                                        "columns": [
                                            { "title": "SSN" },
                                            { "data": data.appseekers[index].ssn},
                                            { "title": "Full Name" },
                                            { "data": data.appseekers[index].first_name + ' '+data.appseekers[index].second_name +' '+data.appseekers[index].middle_name+' '+data.appseekers[index].last_name },
                                            { "title": "Primary phone" },
                                            { "data": data.appseekers[index].phone_1},
                                            { "title": "Secondary phone " },
                                            { "data": data.appseekers[index].phone_2},
                                            { "title": "Secondary phone " },
                                            { "data": data.appseekers[index].evaluation.total_evaluation},
                                        ]
                                    });
                                    });
}
}
}
```

The table empty and without any data,,, the json data is already gotten from the server:
[The json data from the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEpoN.png)

what is wrong in this code? help please